# Geometric tricks in general relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, geometry

So I was quite surprised when I had learned some geometric tricks in school but didn't see them applied in the geometry of general relativity. Here's what I'm talking about, let's say I have $2$ circles:

$$S_1 \equiv x^2 +y^2 - r^2 = 0$$

and:

$$ S_2 \equiv 3(x-a)^2 + 3(x-b)^2 - 27r^2 = 0 $$

Now, let's say I wish to find the equation of a line which passes through the intersection of both these circles. The answer is simply:

$$S_1 - \frac{1}{3} S_2 = 0$$

This works because this combination reduces the above equation to a first degree equation and will pass through the intersection of $S_1$ and $S_2$. Warmup over. Okay, now let's say I have

Now, let's say I have $2$ light cones described by:

$$C_1 \equiv ct^2 - x^2 -y^2 -z^2=0$$

and

$$C_2 \equiv ct^2 -(x-a)^2 -(y-b)^2 -(z-c)^2=0$$

Now,

$$C_1 - C_2 = 0$$

Automatically gives me the hypersurface,

$$ (x,y,z) \cdot (a,b,c)^T = \frac{1}{2 } (a,b,c) \cdot (a,b,c)^T$$

This hypersurface is at the intersection of both light cones. Is it possible to extend these tricks to General relativity?

Comment: Yes, but you can't use flat x,y,z but you have to use the metric tensor

Comment: From your question I am not sure what kind of “geometric tricks” extensions are you looking for. Any GR calculations that could be called “a trick” (the most famous being the Newman–Janis trick)? Calculations using Cartesian coordinates (for example with canonical embedding of dS or AdS metrics)? Calculations involving intersections of curves/surfaces/hypersurfaces?